# Capturando exceções do servidor através de requisição HTTP Java

Tags: java

Olá,
Tenho um sistema que faz a leitura de arquivos XML, transforma em JSON e faz requisições HTTP (POST) para outro servidor salvar os dados no banco. Porém alguns arquivos XML tem, por exemplo, campos nulos que o servidor não permite salvar sem, e então o servidor retorna a exceção. Essa é minha classe de conexão com o servidor:

```
public class Conexao {
public void sendPost(String json, URL url) throws Exception {

    try {

        // Cria um objeto HttpURLConnection:;
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection)  
                url.openConnection();

        try {
            // Define que a conexão pode enviar informações e obtê-las de volta:
            request.setDoOutput(true);
            request.setDoInput(true);

            // Define o content-type:
            request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // Define o método da requisição:
            request.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Conecta na URL:
            request.connect();

            // Escreve o objeto JSON usando o OutputStream da requisição:
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(request.getOutputStream())) {
                outputStream.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                } 

            int response = request.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader br;
            if (200 <= response && response <= 299) {
                //Requisição feita com sucesso
            }  else {
               br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((request.getErrorStream())));
               String resul = br.readLine();
               throw new Exception(" Dados da requisição: " + resul);

                }
           }
        } finally {
            request.disconnect();
          }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw (e);

    }

        }
```

}

Até ai ok, porém preciso capturar essas exceções e mostrar no meu sistema, o porque do arquivo não ter salvado no banco. Quando executo essa função e da erro no servidor, o "resul" me retorna até o HTML do servidor, cheio de informações desnecessárias e na maioria das vezes sem o erro causado. Alguém sabe me dizer se é possível capturar apenas a exceção causada através do response do HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Se você possui controle sobre servidor, o ideal seria que você fornecesse uma API no servidor para o cliente e, caso o cliente passasse informações inválidas, o servidor enviasse como resposta um JSON ou XML descrevendo o erro. Caso você não tenha controle sobre o servidor e só possa contar com a resposta HTML, o que você poderia fazer é utilizar um parser HTML como o [JSOUP](https://jsoup.org/) para tentar pegar o erro dentro do HTML. Sem saber como é a aplicação do servidor ou resposta que ele te dá, fica difícil dar uma resposta objetiva.

Comment: Temos o controle do sim servidor, utilizamos spring boot e hibernate, sabendo disso você indicaria outro recurso para que o servidor retornasse somente os erros? 
Vou dar uma olhada na ferramenta do HTML parser que você me indicou.
Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque o código do servidor responsável por processar a requisição.